# Inline functions in header files in C++

Tags: c++, function, header, multiple-definition-error

Why is it a bad practice to define the functions of the class in the header files?

Lets say I have a header file and I define the functions of the class in the class definition itself like,

headerfile.hpp

```
#ifndef _HEADER_FILE_
#define _HEADER_FILE_

class node{
int i;

public:
int nextn(){
......
return i;
}
}

#endif //_HEADER_FILE_
```

So defining the function in the class like this makes the function "Inline".So if we include this header file in say two .cpp files, will it cause "Multiple definition error" ??Is it a bad practice to define the functions like this in the class definition?

Answer (score 5):

It is a bad practice for the following reasons: If you need to change the code, let's say to add a trace in a simple setter (they are commonly in the .h); then you will need to recompile all CPP files that #includes the change (and any dependency of). In my current project that could reach up to 1 hour lost. If you later need to add another trace, then another and so on you quickly loose 1-2 days or work waiting for the compiler.

If you place your code in the CPP, then you only need to re-link, and that takes only a few minutes. Your project may be small today, but who knows in a few years. It's just a good habit to take.

Another (not so good) reason is that if you search your code base for the string "::MyFonction" you will not find it in the declaration since there is no "::" (we only want implementations). But a good IDE should find it anyway using a context search instead of a string search.

Answer (score 2):

It's not bad practise (in fact it's commonplace) and it will not cause multiple definition errors. Inline functions never cause multiple definition errors, that's one of the meanings of inline.

Comment: So there is nothing wrong with defining the functions in header file like this as long as the functions are small?

Comment: @starkk92 I would agree with that, but it is a style thing, so other people might disagree.

Comment: Since there is no mention of `inline` in the question, you could make the distinction between *inline* and `inline` more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The convention to separate prototypes (that is, the declaration of the class, its functions, their types) from implementation comes from both a design and a performance point of view.

- Type checking and compiling your dependants is cheaper. Something that uses your class can be safely compiled without knowing your implementation.
- Your compiler won't need to parse and recompile the same information lots of times each time you do compile those dependants.

The thing is to remember what it really means with you write `#include` at the top of a file in C++: it means "take all the contents of some other file, and put them here." So if you're using a class in lots of places all over your code base, then it's getting parsed every single time, and re-compiled in the context of that compilation unit.

This is precisely the reason why you *have to* put implementations of *template* classes in-line in the header file; the compiler *needs* to re-parse and compile the class for every different template instantiation (because that's what templates are about).

To answer your question directly: 
* No, you will not get a multiple definition error.
* Maybe, some people would consider it back practice from a design points of view (others wouldn't)
* You *might* see a difference in performance (though not necessarily a degredation, as I believe - though I could be wrong), that despite the above, it can still be faster to compile header-only libraries.

Probably avoid doing this if your implementations are long, the class is used often in the codebase, and will be subject to frequent change.

For further reading, it might be worth checking up on "precompiled headers."

Answer (score 0):

It is legal to define (inline) functions in your hpp file. Note that some people prefer to gather then under a dedicated extension like "inl.hpp", but this is just a style preference.